# Auth0 - login is sending user to Private IP instead of domain name

Tags: authentication, auth0, okta

I'm using Okta Auth0 Universal Login in my application. Everything was working fine until we had some users outside of our network attempt to login. Their login attempts are erring immediately with an invalid callback path error.

Pretend that my origin site is: example.com and my private IP is 10.2.4.01

Auth0 is responding to the login request with https://10.2.4.01/callback instead of https://example.com/callback

I'm not specifying the 10.2.4.01 anywhere, so I'm lost to what configuration is lacking - whether it's something in Auth0 to configure out if it's something on our side. I'm looking into Custom Domains feature on Auth0's Tenant Settings, but haven't been able to enable it yet and unsure if that will fix the issue in the end.